# sending & receiving files with windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have some movie files on my Ubuntu computer that I would like to send to my XP laptop.

Using a USB is too much hassle. Is there any other way of achieving this? Something like the `scp` command would great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are on Ubuntu which has python installed per default you can just run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory of files you want shared. This just creates a webserver on port 8000 that serves whatever is in that folder, so on your Windows Computer you can just point a browser to http://IP_OF_UBUNTU_BOX:8000 and download whatever you need.

Comment: Nice solution. So I'm done with my "Learn something new each day"-task for today :-)

Comment: Glad I could help you with that mate ;)

Comment: Ow, so easy. I'll try tomorrow. But, how to reverse the process?

Answer (score 3):

Install [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) on the Windows machine and use it to connect to the Linux machine. Alternatively, use the Windows mechanisms to create a folder share called e.g. share1 and then under Linux start the file manager nautilus, hit Ctrl+l to get a location text field and write into it smb://192.168.1.24/share1 where you of course have to enter the IP adress or hostname of your windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Share your windows folder over the network and your linux computer should be able to access it via Samba.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a desktop on your Ubuntu machine, you should be able to right click on the folder that contains the items you wish to share. Start by right-clicking the folder you want to share, and select Share Folder. If the services required to share files/folders aren’t installed, you’ll be prompted to install them. After clicking Install services they will automatically start to download and install.

Once that has completed you’ll be presented with an options window. From here you can select the type of sharing (SMB or NFS), give the shared folder a name and decide if you want read-only access to the folder. Click OK when you’re done.

Now open a terminal in Ubuntu and enter the command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
```

Samba user should now be added.

And now other computers
can connect to your shared folder..